# C#: Replace Text Of Blank Items In Listview?

Tags: c#, windows, forms, listview

How would I go about about replacing the text of blank items in column 5 of my listView with the word "No"?

I tried this but it threw an `InvalidArgument=Value of '4' is not valid for 'index'.` error:

```
 foreach (ListViewItem i in listView1.Items)
 {
     if (i.SubItems[4].Text == " ")
     {
         i.SubItems[4].Text = i.SubItems[4].Text.Replace(" ", "No");
     }
 }
```

Comment: Did you make sure that `i.SubItems[4]` is a valid object within `listView.Items`? Have a great day :)

Comment: @PicrofoEGY Yes its a column in my listView is 4.

Comment: Are you really sure? `i.SubItems[4]` and `listView1.Items[4]` are two different items. Have a great day :)

Comment: Edwin it may be a Column in your listView but the question Picrofo is asking is is there data or is there a null value..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE There is not a specific item. I basically want to replace any blank/null items with the word No in column 5 of my listView.

Comment: Then you need to check for if value is Null or if it's a string then check if string.IsNullOrEmpty() empty and null are not the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code provided above will get all items within `ListView1.Items` and check if the sub-item of index `4` and its property `Text` is equal to   which may result in the described error if the index exceeds the array limit. You may avoid this by making sure that this item is not `Nothing`.

**Example**

```
foreach (ListViewItem i in listView1.Items) //Get all items in listView1.Items
{
   if (i.SubItems.Count > 3) //Continue if i.SubItems.Count is more than 3 (The array contains i.SubItems[3] which refers to an item within the 4th column (i.SubItems.Count is not an array. Therefore, it'll start with 1 instead of 0))
   {
       if (i.SubItems[3].Text == " ") //Continue if i.SubItems[3].Text is equal to  
       {
            i.SubItems[3].Text = i.SubItems[3].Text.Replace(" ", "No"); //Replace   with No
       }
   }
}
```

**Notice**: Arrays are zero-indexed which means that they start with 0 instead of 1.

**Notice**: If you only have 4 columns, `i.SubItems.Count` would be 4 and not 3 because it's a normal `int` **considering that all columns are filled**.

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)

Comment: Hey! Which example should I use? I am trying to replace the text of any items under column 5 of my listView that do not contain the word Yes and/or are blank. This does not reflect to a specific item but all items under a column.

What example should I use? Also I tried example 1 and 2 and the first got me an error and the second one nothing happened.

Comment: @EdwinTorres Oh, you have a column in the `ListView`. Sorry for misunderstanding, in this case, you may use the first example. If this returned an error, may you please provide the error returned? :)

Comment: Sure the error is: InvalidArgument=Value of '4' is not valid for 'index'. Parameter name: index

Comment: @EdwinTorres The above code works for me if I have 5 or more columns as the target is set to the 5th column. Please remember that arrays are Zero-Indexed this means that they start with ZERO and not ONE. If the target column is `4`. Then, you may change `i.SubItems[4]` to `i.SubItems[3]`. In this case, the target column will be set to the 4th. Have a great day :)

Comment: @EdwinTorres I have edited my answer! I hope you get your problem resolved. Have a great day :)

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I'd [Use the debugger](http://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging) to figure out what's actually going on.

You can check and see what's actually in `i.SubItems`, and make sure it's actually what you think it is.

The only possible thing i can think of is maybe you made a typo somewhere or that `i.SubItems[4]` actually just isn't valid.

maybe you're iterating through some of your list items, but not all of your list items have 5 columns, or maybe some are empty.

Answer (score 1):

Once you get that first error figured out, your logic for replacing the text might work better like this:

```
if (i.SubItems != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(i.SubItems[4].Text))
{
    i.SubItems[4].Text = "No";
}
```